# Real-time IIS monitoring

Tags: windows, performance, monitoring, performance-monitoring, perfmon

We're looking for some monitoring software that will report and display real-time performance information for IIS.  We're currently using perfmon to monitor requests executing, requests queued, etc..., but we're looking for a permanent solution that is able to generate reports, charts, and more.

Nagios seems to get a lot of praise, but we are looking for something that we can install on Windows.  I stumbled across [Nimsoft](http://www.nimsoft.com/solutions/datacenter-network/applications/iis.php), but was wondering if there are any alternatives?

We are only looking to monitor our web servers (less than 5 machines).

Comment: This is fairly difficult to do due to the fact that IIS does not write its logs in real time by default, and if you enable real time logs (which is difficult) then you can't write it into the format that most log parsers and analysis programs support.

Comment: I was hoping there was something out there that reads from the performance counters rather than logs.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you said you'd like something that you can install on windows but I really haven't seen many "good" options available.

I'd like to make a recommendation any way just in case you decide to brave the linux world :)  If you have at least one linux machine.. or a place you can run virtuals then look into Zabbix as they also have a virtual machine which is nice.  It's open source and can do exactly what you're asking (I know this because I do it).  It can take perfmon counters and translate them into graphs that it stores real time.  We have perf counters graphing into zabbix for IIS servers, NginX servers, MSSQL, Memcached and a variety of other things that matter to us.  It took some setup time and some research but it's quite powerful.

We even have reports built that over-lay graphs - for example I have a graph built that shows me the inbound/outbound requests for all of my web servers, their CPU usage and overlapped on top of that a graph during the same time frame that shows me the cpu usage on my SQL server as well as the number of queries against it, and overlapped on top of THAT is the number of cache/hits and misses during the time frame.  Might be a little over complicated of an example for what you're looking for, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't specifically know if it supports performance counters vs log files but you might take a look at SolarWinds [Orion APM](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/orion/application_monitor/).